# how to create a File Dialog in python using PyQt5

Tags: python, directory, pyqt5, qfiledialog

i have python class called PDFviewer that upon run the program the system display a window that handle button **(open folder)** witch will open a file Dialog that allow the user to choose a directory and display files inside it.

the problem is that when i try to click the  button the system crash and display this error :

> File
>   "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\final_project\myPDFviewer.py",
>   line 36, in    sys.exit(app.exec_()) File
>   "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\final_project\myPDFviewer.py",
>   line 24, in setExistingDirectory   options=options)
>
> builtins.TypeError: getExistingDirectory(parent: QWidget = None,
>   caption: str = '', directory: str = '', options:
>   Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] =
>   QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'

## code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
                             QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton)

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt

import pdfviewer

class pdfViewer(pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow):

    def __init__(self,PdfPreviewObj ):
        self.PdfPreviewObj =PdfPreviewObj 
        self.setupUi(PdfPreviewObj)
        self.PdfPreviewObj.show()
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.clicked.connect(self.setExistingDirectory)



    def setExistingDirectory(self,qf):    
        options = QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                     "Open Folder",
                options=options)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PdfPreviewWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    pdfViewerUi = pdfViewer(PdfPreviewWindow)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution   it did not work before because i wasn't refer the object dialog to **self** so the solution become :

```
def setExistingDirectory(self): 
    self.dialog = Dialog()
    options = QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
    self.directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.dialog, "Open Folder" ,options=options)
    self.dialog.show()
```

Comment: Mark yourself as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Selecting files:

```
filepath = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select File')
```

Here, `self` represents the parent window usually the **mainWindow**.

#### Similarly, for selecting folder:

```
folderpath = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Folder')
```